# How can I query delll boomi MDH field thats not in match rule?

Tags: boomi

I am new to MDH and I would like to know how to query MDH field directly thats not in match rules.

I have a model that has 5 fields (Src_id, name, email, updated_date, created_date) and we have a match rule on Src_id which is also ID in MDH.

But, I would like to search on name and get the Src_Id is it possible? if not, do I need to make any changes to my model

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two avenues for "querying" your master data hub.

1. MDH Web UI
2. Boomi MDH API

You say you would like to search "Name" and get "Src_Id". If you using avenue
(1) - you simply go to UI and select "Add Filter"->"Field Data"->select "Name"->select operator "Equals"->{fill in name you'd like to search for} --> The entire Golden Record is returned and you can see it via the UI or by clicking the timestamp to pull up the record in depth
(2) refer to https://help.boomi.com/bundle/hub/page/r-mdm-REST_APIs.html
specifically "Query Golden Record". You would fill in all the necessary API information (URL)+Basic Auth based on Repository+universe id-based on model, etc.
Your request body would look like:

```
<RecordQueryRequest>
<view>
<fieldId>SRC_ID</fieldId>
</view>
<filter>
<fieldValue>
<fieldId>NAME</fieldId>
<operator>EQUALS</operator>
<value>{INSERT NAME TO SEARCH}</value>
</fieldValue>
</filter>
</RecordQueryRequest>
```

Response will be in XML corresponding to your model: eg)

```
<RecordQueryResponse resultCount="1" totalCount="1">
<Record recordId="GUID" createdDate="TIMESTAMP" updatedDate="TIMESTAMP" recordTitle="DERIVED BY MODEL">
<Fields>
<rootelementname>
<src_id>123</src_id>
</rootelementname>
</Fields>
</RecordQueryResponse>
```